# MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() Equivalent for SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is there a way that this full-text searching query could be translated from MySQL into SQL Server?

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title) AGAINST('My Title' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM books
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('My Title' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC,
books.title ASC
```

If it helps, I am specifically using SQL Server 2000. I don't have the option of using a more recent version. :S

Here is a sample scenario.

---

Create the table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `books`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

--
-- Index the title column
--

ALTER TABLE `books` ADD INDEX ( `title` )

--
-- Dumping data for table `books`
--

INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'My Title'),
(2, 'My Title'),
(3, 'Not My Title'),
(4, 'Other Title'),
(5, 'Not Related'),
(6, 'Not Related Either');
```

Execute the query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title) AGAINST('My Title' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM books
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('My Title' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC,
books.title ASC
```

Here is what is returned:

```
id  title           score
1   My Title        1
2   My Title        1
3   Not My Title    1
4   Other Title     1
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For the benefit of those of us who know SQL Server but don't know MySQL, could you explain what `MATCH() AGAINST()` does? Preferably with an example - sample data and desired results. This seems like you are after Full-Text Search but that is just a guess from the query.

Comment: No problem. MATCH() takes an indexed column within MySQL table and matches against a string that is passed into AGAINST(). It doesn't look for equivalent strings as `column = 'string'` would, but it returns similar results. It is also significantly more useful than `LIKE %string%`. Sorting by the "score" alias allows results that are most closely related to the string to show first. Here is the article that I which taught me how to write queryies to do full-text searching: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated the question with a sample. Yes, this is full text searching.

Comment: Does "score" represent the number of times the word appeared in the string, or is the algorithm more complex than that?

Comment: MySQL automatically calculates a "score" alias. This score is usually something like .9823475 or .124874, but always larger than zero. It can range up above 1, and even at 4 sometimes. It doesn't not count the number of occurrences, but ranks the accuracy of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a case for implementing Full-Text Search. It sounds like the algorithm you're after is much more complex than those offered by [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql), [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) and [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), which are very simple on/off type results (either the string contains the searched expression or it doesn't).

The official Microsoft documentation for Full-Text Search [starts here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search). [This article may also be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search), as well as this MSDN article, ["Improve the performance of full-text indexing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/improve-the-performance-of-full-text-indexes), and some of [these Full-Text Search tips on mssqltips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/32/full-text-search/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

The Full-Text keywords you're probably most interested in are [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql) and [`CONTAINSTABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql). [This page describes, among other things, how CONTAINSTABLE applies ranking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms142524(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Woo-hoo! Just what I needed, Aaron! Thank you for your help. +1 and answer accepted!